# I want to write a set of classes that build a set of related - but different - objects, What is the best design pattern for this?

Tags: design-patterns, solid-principles, code-reuse

I'm working on a project where there is a set of objects that the program builds them using configuration files that describe each object's attributes.

Here's some description about these objects' classes :

- Each class belongs to only one of three categories **A**, **B**, **C**.
- Each class in any category differs in its attributes from the classes in the same category. So I can't write a generic class to build instances from classes in a certain class category.
- Building an instance from any class in any category is **NOT** a complicated process.

Now the question is : If I want to implement - or say adapt - SOLID principles, clean code, and some design patterns in the project to make the code maintainable, flexible, reusable, extensible and readable, should I :

- Write a builder class for each category, that each class in this category has a method to build an instance of it from within its category builder class (e.g builder class for category **A** and a builder method for every class in this category),
- or should I write a builder class for each class regardless of to any category that class belongs ? (e.g class **1** that belongs to category **A** has its builder class, and class **2** that belongs to category **C** has its builder class and so on) .

*Please don't mix what I'm trying to do with the regular serialization, here the configuration files are written by the user*

Comment: Could you give some examples of categories and classes? What do the classes of the same category share?

Comment: I really wanted to share some code but unfortunately I'm not the owner of the project so can't share real examples. But each category inherit from a class, classes in any one category don't act together in the code, they has some classes that aggregate them.

Comment: Does each category have an interface: interface A, interface B, interface C? Does the client require one instance from each category or multiple (different) instances from each category?